# Regex - negative lookahead with lazy limit?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm not a regex expert, but after a couple hours I've built this regex:

```
#\[url=(?!.*?<div onclick="unveil_spoiler.*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\]#i
```

Which is a case-insensitive:

```
\[url=(?!.*?<div onclick="unveil_spoiler.*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\]
```

To match `[url=xxxx://yyyy]zzzz[/url]` patterns, except if it contains a `<div onclick="unveil_spoiler` string between `[url=` and and `[/url]`.

Now I'm trying to add a similar check, to don't return a match if it contains a `\[url.*?\]` between the `\[url=` and `\[/url\]`. I've tried many ways but I can seem to find a 100% working one.

First I tried adding another negative lookahead very similar to the one already present in my regex, which works partially, but then it seems like the lookahead goes through until the end of the line - until the last `\[/url\]` - for each match, I wanted the lookahead to stop at the first `\[/url\]` as the capturing group does.

Here's a string for debugging:

```
[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.nomatch.com<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"]No match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.nomatch.com]<div onclick="unveil_spoiler" No match[/url]
[url=http://www.nomatch.com]No <div onclick="unveil_spoiler"match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.nomatch.com]No <div onclick="unveil_spoiler" match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]

[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com][b]Match[/b][/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]

[url=http://www.thisshouldntmatch.com[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]This shouldn't match[/url]

[url=http://www.thisshouldntmatch.com[url=http://www.thisshouldntmatch.com[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]]This shouldn't match[/url]This shouldn't match[/url]

[url=http://www.thisshouldntmatch.com[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]This shouldn't match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]

[url=http://www.thisshouldntmatch.com]This shouldn't match[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][/url]

[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]
```

With the regex posted in the beginning of the post, it'll match the 2 matches in the first line perfectly. Now I wanted it to don't return a match when there's a `\[url.*?\]` inside of the match, I've tried this regex:

```
\[url=(?!.*?\[url.*?\].*?\[/url.*?\])(?!.*?<div onclick="unveil_spoiler.*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\]
```

And this:

```
\[url=(?!.*?(?:<div onclick="unveil_spoiler|\[url.*?\]).*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\]
```

Which won't return matches when there's a `\[url.*?\]` inside of the match, but then it also stops matching the first match of the first line (in the example string) which it should (and as the first regex does). That is, it'll only match the last valid match of each line then.

I think it's a problem with the lookahead which doesn't stop at the first `\[/url\]`, is there any way to make it lazy/fix it then?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

`\[url=[^\[<]*?\](?:(?!(\[url)|<).)*?\[\/url\]`

http://regexr.com?30mna

Comment: Works better than mine, but still it'll only match the first and last valid matches in each line e.g. `[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]` Edited the first post to include this string.

Comment: I've edited your first regex slightly, `((\[url=(?!.*?(?:<div onclick="unveil_spoiler|\[url.*?\]).*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\])|(?<=.*?\[url.*?)\[url=.*?url\])` does ALMOST what I want, except that it won't match the very first `[url=` in the string, is there any way to fix this? Oh sec trying your second one.

Comment: Check my update.  I think it fits your requirements.  It's just an extra OR condition to search for.

Comment: `\[url=[^\[]*?\][^\[]*?\[\/url\]` I see, it does work for most of the string, however, by negating the `[]` it won't match `[url=http://www.match.com][b]Match[/b][/url]` nor check for the `<div onclick="unveil_spoiler` and I don't really want to block the `[]` character class inside the `\[url=.*?\[/url\]`

Comment: Hmm I see, maybe you can post a few more lines of example text that you're trying to match.

Comment: I've edited the example in the first post to include it, also, if you try `((\[url=(?!.*?(?:<div onclick="unveil_spoiler|\[url.*?\]).*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\])|(?<=.*?\[url.*?)\[url=.*?url\])` it'll return all matches I want except the first match when the first match is valid and there's more than one match per line.

Comment: Ok try this `\[url=[^\[]*?\](?:(?!\[url).)*?\[\/url\]` with your updated text.

Comment: Seems to work, even though it doesn't check if the first capture has `://` neither for the `<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"`

Comment: I think you need to post some example texts with `<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"` so people can more accurately test it.  Why don't you just post your test file? Your sample texts don't tell me what's not being matched.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I forgot to add one of those, ok, I added 2 lines of examples with those at the beginning of the string. Feel free to try but I'll probably just replace that regex by a loop.

Comment: Woah, man if I wasn't re-doing this phpbb's patterns for free I'd credit you a good cut. :) Thanks for all the hard work and dedication.

Comment: It's np.  I believe that you only need `\[url=[^\[]*?\](?:(?!\[url).)*?\[\/url\]` though instead of that whole pattern.

Comment: I see, the main problem is that this regex is to be applied in a phpbb2 application, hence it needs different patterns for URLs with protocol and without it (that's what the `://` check is for). The `spoiler` check is to prevent an exploit with the spoiler implementation. Since I have 8 patterns which I need to adapt, it might be better to do the replaces manually inside a loop (and that would be less cpu-consuming server-side too). I'll check which one is more viable, thanks for the help again. :)

Comment: Ah, I've edited your regex slightly: `((\[url=(?!.*?(?:<div onclick="unveil_spoiler|\[url.*?\]).*?\[/url\])([^_\W]+?://.*?)\](.+?)\[/url\])|\[url=[^\[<]*?\](?:(?!(\[url)|<div onclick="unveil_spoiler").)*?\[\/url\])` now it'll allow for `<` inside the capturable groups. =]

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work:

```
\[url=(?:(?!<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"|\[url.*?\].*?\[/url.*?\]).)*?([^_\W]+?://[^\[\]]*)\]((?:(?!\[/?url).)*)\[/url\]
```

http://rubular.com/r/7h9EJ0casb

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine, I'm debugging it with a couple more examples to make sure.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I just made a slight edit because I realized the capture group wasn't doing the right thing.

Comment: Yes, by "slight edit" you mean I'll take the rest of the night to understand it and adapt for the other 7 patterns, nevertheless it works great in this scope. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Oh there's just a slightly problem, it's capturing matches with `<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"` as in `[url=http://www.nomatch.com<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"]No match[/url][url=http://www.nomatch.com]<div onclick="unveil_spoiler" No match[/url]`

Comment: I've moved the lookahead, now it works fine `\[url=(?!.*?<div onclick="unveil_spoiler")(?:(?!\[url.*?\].*?\[/url.*?\]).)*?([^_\W]+?://[^\[\]]*)\]((?:(?!\[/?url).)*)\[/url\]`

Comment: With the regex above it won't match the first valid match in `[url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url][url=http://www.nomatch.com<div onclick="unveil_spoiler"]No match[/url][url=http://www.match.com]Match[/url]` gah I'll probably just remove the spoiler check at this rate.